# Adding prefixes that depend on codes to those codes

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have cells in **Column B**:

```
081603323W400
081603323W400
161603323W402
161603323W402
```

and need a formula for adding a prefix to these numbers (to be shown in **Column A**) that will look at the last two digits of the numbers in **Column B** and use these numbers to create a prefix that begins `1`.

Examples:

"081603323W4**00**" - needs the become "**100**081603323W400" and
"161603323W4**02**` - needs the become "**102**161603323W402"

Comment: @pnuts Myself, I don't see all that much difference between providing a formula, vs providing VBA code. But I wouldn't object to things evolving.

Comment: @pnuts I'll take a look later on.  Busy now.  Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

Seems:

```
=1&RIGHT(B1,2)&B1
```

(to be copied down) was deemed fit for purpose.